# How to save GORM class with composite id made from its own field?

Tags: grails-orm, grails-2.0

This is my Domain class

```
 class ReturnReason implements Serializable {

                Long returnReasonId
                Long languageId
                String name

                int hashCode() {
                    def builder = new HashCodeBuilder()
                    builder.append returnReasonId
                    builder.append languageId
                    builder.toHashCode()
                }

                boolean equals(other) {
                    if (other == null) return false
                    def builder = new EqualsBuilder()
                    builder.append returnReasonId, other.returnReasonId
                    builder.append languageId, other.languageId
                    builder.isEquals()
                }

                static mapping = {
                    id composite: ["returnReasonId", "languageId"]
                    version false
                }

                static constraints = {
                    name maxSize: 128
                }
            }
```

This is my controller code to save my domain class.

```
def save() {
    ReturnReason returnReasonInstance = new ReturnReason(params)
    returnReasonInstance.languageId = 1
    if (!returnReasonInstance.save(flush: true)) {
        render(view: "create", model: [returnReasonInstance: returnReasonInstance])
    }
    redirect(action: "list")
}
```

While trying to save in my controller than there is a error in returnReasonId ,i.e returnReasonId rejected value null. How to fix it.??

Answer (score 0):

write validate:false in save action

```
def save() {
    ReturnStatus returnStatusInstance = new ReturnStatus(params)
    returnStatusInstance.languageId = 1
    if (!returnStatusInstance.save(validate: false, flush: true)) {
        render(view: "create", model: [returnStatusInstance: returnStatusInstance])
    }
    redirect(action: "list")
}
```